# What happens if I perform a commit( ) on an IndexWriter which is opened on a prior commit in Lucene?

Tags: commit, lucene

As I went through this wonderful [blog by Mike McCandless](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/03/transactional-lucene.html) explaining the power of Lucene's Transactional features and the one where we can save older commits and open our indexwriter on a prior commit. But immediately this scenario came up in my mind. Does it create some kind of a branch internally for the new commit performed on a prior commit or does it just replace all the newer commits after that prior commit and just retaining the recent commit that I just performed on that prior commit?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it creates a branch: the new commit will reflect the old one you had opened, plus any changes you made during the indexing session.  What happens to the future commits (after the one you had opened) is up to your deletion policy.  If it saves those commits, then at any time you are free to open a writer against one of them, making a branch from them as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force a commit, call commit(), or, close the writer. **Once a commit has finished, newly opened IndexReader instances will see the changes to the index as of that commit**. When running in this mode, be careful not to refresh your readers while optimize or segment merges are taking place as this can tie up substantial disk space.

Regardless of autoCommit, an IndexReader or IndexSearcher will only see the index as of the "point in time" that it was opened. Any changes committed to the index after the reader was opened are not visible until the reader is re-opened.

```
void commit()
      Commits all pending changes (added & deleted documents, optimizations, segment merges, added indexes, etc.) to the index, and syncs all referenced index files, such that a reader will see the changes and the index updates will survive an OS or machine crash or power loss.

void commit(Map commitUserData)
      Commits all changes to the index, specifying a commitUserData Map (String -> String).
```

Comment: Well, you are right. But here I am specifically interested in the case when performing commit on the indexWriter which is opened on a prior commit.